# git merge with multiple parent loss parent

Tags: git

I have a tree look like this

```
* b
|\
| * a
|/
* master,m
```

now I want to merge **a and b** into master

```
git checkout m
git merge --no-ff a b
```

but it gives

```
* m
|\
| * b
| |\
| | * a
| |/
| /
|/
* master
```

which shows m has no parent `a` after merge.

Is this expected behavior? 
can I do what I want (`m` has parents `master`,`b`, and `a`)? better just use single (merge) command.

---

this script reproduce the situation

```
git init
git commit --allow-empty -m "init"
git branch m
git branch a
git branch b
git checkout a
git commit --allow-empty -m "a"
git checkout b
git merge --no-ff a
git checkout m
git merge --no-ff a b
```

`git --version: 2.16.2.windows.1`

Comment: What's the expected final state? Why do you merge b into a?

Comment: @choroba expected final state is `a` becomes parent of `m`. I merge `b` into `a` because `b` use some features from `a`. and merge into `m` because it's github pages in this case

Comment: Since `b` is ahead of `a` or `a` is included by `b`,  after `git merge b`, `m` naturally includes `a`. I don't think `git-merge` would take `a` as a parent of `m` in this case. When X is ahead of Y, `git merge Y` to X results in `Already up-to-date`.

Comment: In 2.13.6 on Linux, I'm getting different structure: `a` **is** parent of `m`.

Comment: @choroba thanks, do you know which is correct behavior?

Comment: @choroba sorry it seems I exchange `a` and `b` in script. is `m` have 3 parent in your case?

Comment: No, two: `a` and `master`.

Comment: @ElpieKay I think `no-ff` would create a commit with 2 parent anyway (in this case 3 parent).

Comment: @choroba thanks, then we have same structure, do you know is this correct behavior?

Comment: @appleapple It would if `a` and `b` were diverged in this case. For example, you make another commit to `a` and then merge `a` and `b` to `m` with `--no-ff`.

Comment: @ElpieKay I know it would, I just want to know why it ignore `a`. If I just want `b`, I would `git merge b`, not `a b`. and `--no-ff` always work even if there is no commit (it shows Already up-to-date but create a commit). and `a->b b->a a->b b->a` actually create 4 commit

Comment: @appleapple If `git merge a --no-ff` to `b`, it will show `Already up-to-date` and no new commit is made. I'm not familiar with the internal algorithm, but I guess for an octopus merge involving more than two heads it ignores any head that is an ancestor of another head. BTW, I tried with git version 2.10.0.windows.1.

Comment: @ElpieKay it's not the case for me... [imgur](https://imgur.com/a/Fpygp)

Comment: @ElpieKay oh I got what you said. but it still strange to me.

Comment: @ElpieKay If I commit to b and do the `a b -> m`, the same happens, but absolutely  `a -> b` can produce a commit.

Comment: @appleapple If `a -> b` means `git checkout b && git merge a`, then based on the first graph in the question, where `b` is ahead of `a` and `a` is a parent of `b`, no new commit is expected except that it echoes `Already up-to-date.`. If `a -> b` means `git checkout a && git merge b --no-ff`, a new merge commit will be produced.

Comment: @ElpieKay oh, I mess it up. it should be `b -> a`, i.e. the second situation. Anyway `checkout m` then `merge a b` and `merge b a` makes no difference. I would like git just set parents as-is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This *is* the normal behavior.

There are two parts to merging:

1. Derive the correct source tree for a snapshot.
2. Produce the correct updated commit graph.

We'll assume here that step 1 has magically been taken care of. :-)  That is, we'll concern ourselves only with the final commit graph.

Merging, whether octopus or not, in Git involves making sure that the final commit chosen has all the input commits as ancestors.  If your current commit is an ancestor of all your proposed merge commits, the merge *can* be done as a fast-forward operation, and by default, *will* be done as a fast-forward operation.

The drawback here is that sometimes we wish to distinguish, via `--first-parent`, a singular line of commits that represent a branch.  If Git were to do a fast-forward operation, this line would (at least potentially) be destroyed by mingling other first-parents of other merge commits.  For instance, in your case, `b` points to a merge commit with parents labeled `a` (on one side) and then `master` and `m` (on the other).  So Git offers `--no-ff` to force a real merge, by making a new commit whose first parent is the current commit.

But, even for a multiple-head "octopus" merge, if your argument commit names or hash IDs are ancestors of each other, Git will drop the one(s) that are ancestors: since `a` is an ancestor of `b`, Git does not have to use `a` to produce *either* a correct graph *or* the correct source code snapshot—so it just doesn't.

There's no fundamental reason that Git could not include *both* `b` *and* `a` as parents—second and third, probably in that order—of the new merge commit.  All the usual algorithms will continue to work.  It's just *unnecessary*.

Comment: so there is nothing like `git merge --all-parent-exactly`, right?

Comment: Right. Note that you can write your own Git commands: running `git xyz` makes Git search for the `git-xyz` command, so if you want to write an alternative version of `git merge` and call it `git applemerge`, just write a program—this can be a shell script—and call it `git-applemerge` and then `git applemerge` will run your program.

Comment: thanks for the tip. do you know why `.bat` cannot be run this way while `.exe` success? (or I'd better ask new question?)

Comment: That, I have no idea, but it sounds like a Windows thing (`.bat` and `.exe` in particular sound very Windows-y). I avoid Windows myself.

Answer (score 1):

I have done this by using git `write-tree` and `commit-tree`. But I'm looking for simpler (high-level) solution.

---

```
... after merge into m

> git checkout m
> git write-tree
4b825dc642cb6eb9a060e54bf8d69288fbee4904
> git commit-tree 4b82 -p master -p a -p b -m "message"
4663c5272f635e688c93fd3061aeb6317dd9c86f
> git update-ref refs/heads/m 4663
```