# git alias not found bat file

Tags: windows, git, windows-10

from my [last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49747635/git-merge-with-multiple-parent-loss-parent/49756628?noredirect=1#comment86548985_49756628) I learned I can use `git xxx` to invoke `git-xxx`.

When I try it. I found `.bat` is not found while `.exe` execute successfully.

I would like to know what's happened here.

`git --version: 2.16.2.windows.1`

`windows version: windows 10 home 1709 16299.371`

---

--Example--

git-a.cpp -> git-a.exe

```
#include <iostream>
int main(){std::cout <<"a";}
```

git-b.cpp -> git-b.exe

```
#include <cstdlib>
int main(){std::system("git-x");}
```

git-x.bat

```
@echo x
```

command

```
C:\path>git a
a
C:\path>git b
x

C:\path>git x
git: 'x' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.

The most similar commands are
        a
        b

C:\path>git-x
x
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`git bash` can execute exe or shell script.

If, instead of a `gix-x.cmd`, you write a `git-x` (no extension) with

```
#!/bin/sh
echo x
```

That would work too.

Exe are working because there don't need any interpretation, and are making system calls.
Bat would not work because they need *interpretation* by the shell, and a bash shell doesn't know how to interpret a bat *script*.

Comment: It shows `fatal: 'a' appears to be a git command, but we were not
able to execute it. Maybe git-a is broken?` all of `git bash` `git cmd` `cmd` produce same result.

Comment: @appleapple you mean, when you create a `git-a` file script (no extension), as a shell, with a `#!/bin/sh` in its first line?

Comment: sorry, It seems I mistype it to `#!/bin.sh`. it does work now, thanks.

Comment: @appleapple No, that is the all point: a bash can execute a shell script, or a binary making system calls only.

Comment: @appleapple a bat is a windows *interpreted* script, and a bash wouldn't know how to *interpret* it. It only knows how to *execute* a binary.

Comment: but `git a.bat` execute well. I guess git just invoke it. but since `system("git-a")` in `c++` can invoke it without extension. I think there is something in git prevent this happens.

Comment: @appleapple agreed. Make sure to use different letters (than just "a") to avoid any confusion between what script git is actually executing.

Comment: well, I don't think I ever named my script `git-a.bat`. But even after rename it to `git-20180413.bat`. Still `git 20180413.bat` success and `git 20180413` fail. (and `system("git-20180413")` in `c++` success)